# Phonegap - First app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am building my first app using Phonegap for iOS. I am trying to get the accelerometer values and display it as an alert on the screen. I have the latest version of cordova-2.3.0. Here's the code for the index.html file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap Device Ready Example</title>
        <script type=”text/javascript” charset=”utf-8” src=”cordova-2.3.0.js”></script>
        <script type=”text/javascript” charset=”utf-8”>
            document.addEventListener(“deviceready”, onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
            }

            // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
            //
            function onSuccess(acceleration) {
                alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
                      'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
                      'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
                      'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
            }

            // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
            //
            function onError() {
                alert('onError!');
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Example </h1>
        <p>getCurrentAcceleration </p>
    </body
</html>
```

However, nothing happens. I get a white screen with Example and getCurrentAcceleration written on it.

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know if its your problem, but you have miss closing tag in the end of your body, its look like
   `</body.`
2. ensure that you have this line in your config.xml file:

   `<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />`
3. Is there any other phonegap functions such as navigator.notification.alert work well? maybe your project doesn't setup correctly?
4. ensure also cordova-2.3.0.js is for the iOS version one.

Comment: 1. The body tag is fine in XCode. The formatting seems to be messed up on stackoverflow
2. What line ?
3. The project is setup correctly. I was able to get the default code up and running correctly.
4. I don't understand this point very well

Comment: is my solution helped you?

Comment: No. I still don't see anything